# How can I make the user add a new field using a button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script posted down below, and I want the user to add a new field, when the new field gets added I want a new var to be added.
Live example:
User clicks on the "add new field"
var gets added below var Reason2 called Reason3, Reason4, etc.
"Reason Three: " +Reason3+ gets added below Reason Two on line 51.

I don't have an idea of how to do the above honestly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<form name="TRF" method="post">
  <p style="color:white">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="text-center">Accepted Format</h1>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
              <h6 class="text-uppercase"><strong><center>Accepted Format</center></strong></h6>
              <table style="width:100%" id="theTable">
                <tr>
                  <td>Applicant's Name:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="accname" size="75" placeholder="" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Reason 1:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="R1" size="75" placeholder="" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td id="bla">Reason 2:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="R2" size="75" placeholder="" required></td>
                </tr>

              </table>
              <h3>CODE:</h3>
              <textarea  id="box" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
              <p><a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="generateCode2()" role="button">GENERATE CODE</a></p>


            </div>
            <button id="newField">
            add new field
            </button>
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function generateCode2() {
    var AccoutName = document.forms["TRF"]["accname"].value;
    var Reason1 = document.forms["TRF"]["R1"].value;
      var Reason2 = document.forms["TRF"]["R2"].value;



    document.getElementById("box").value =
"[center][img width=500 height=500]https://i.imgur.com/FuxDfcy.png[/img][/center]"+
"[hr]"+
"\n"+
"[b]Dear[/b] "+AccoutName+
"\n"+
"After reading your Application, Imperials staffs have decided to [color=green][b]Accept[/b][/color] you. "+
"\n"+
"Reason One: " +Reason1+
"\n"+
"Reason Two: " +Reason2+
"\n"+
"Welcome to the Family. "+
"\n"+

""
}
var newField = document.getElementById("newField");
var counter = 3;

function createNewField() {
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var td1 = document.createElement("td");
  var td2 = document.createElement("td");
  td1.innerHTML = "Reason " + counter + ":";
  var inp = document.createElement("input");
  inp.type = "text";
  inp.size = "75";
  inp.name = "R" + counter;
  inp.value=document.getElementById("box").value;
  td2.appendChild(inp);

  document.getElementById("theTable").appendChild(tr);

  tr.appendChild(td1);
  tr.appendChild(td2);

  counter++;
}
newField.addEventListener("click", createNewField);
(function () {
    var onload = window.onload;

    window.onload = function () {
        if (typeof onload == "function") {
            onload.apply(this, arguments);
        }

        var fields = [];
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");

        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            fields.push(inputs[i]);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < textareas.length; i++) {
            fields.push(textareas[i]);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            var field = fields[i];

            if (typeof field.onpaste != "function" && !!field.getAttribute("onpaste")) {
                field.onpaste = eval("(function () { " + field.getAttribute("onpaste") + " })");
            }

            if (typeof field.onpaste == "function") {
                var oninput = field.oninput;

                field.oninput = function () {
                    if (typeof oninput == "function") {
                        oninput.apply(this, arguments);
                    }

                    if (typeof this.previousValue == "undefined") {
                        this.previousValue = this.value;
                    }

                    var pasted = (Math.abs(this.previousValue.length - this.value.length) > 1 && this.value != "");

                    if (pasted && !this.onpaste.apply(this, arguments)) {
                        this.value = this.previousValue;
                    }

                    this.previousValue = this.value;
                };

                if (field.addEventListener) {
                    field.addEventListener("input", field.oninput, false);
                } else if (field.attachEvent) {
                    field.attachEvent("oninput", field.oninput);
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();
</script>
</head>
</color>
</font>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

User clicks on the "add new field"
var gets added below var Reason2 called Reason3, Reason4, etc.
"Reason Three: " +Reason3+ gets added below Reason Two on line 51.

Comment: do you want to use vanilla js or is jquery ok

Comment: It doesn't really matter honestly, as long as I can get the result I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript it's possible to create html elements at runtime using the **createElement()** function. In your case we need to create quite a lot of individual elements to replicate the structure of the table. Those are `<tr>` `<td>` `<input>`.
The **tr** element needs to be added to the **table**, the **td** containing the text 'Reason #:' as well as the **td** holding the **input** element are childs of **tr**. To add a dynamically created element to the DOM, the **appendChild()** function is used.

The input element needs some special treatment because it contains an unique id. The two html-made elements you have are 'R1' and 'R2' - so a new one should follow that pattern and start with 3. This is done by setting up a global variable , appending it to the name and increment it afterwards.

Finally we need to add a 'Create new field' button.

Take a look at this example (you have to scroll down to see the button):

```js
var newField = document.getElementById("newField");
var counter = 3;

function createNewField() {
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  var td1 = document.createElement("td");
  var td2 = document.createElement("td");
  td1.innerHTML = "Reason " + counter + ":";
  var inp = document.createElement("input");
  inp.type = "text";
  inp.size = "75";
  inp.name = "R" + counter;
  td2.appendChild(inp);

  document.getElementById("theTable").appendChild(tr);

  tr.appendChild(td1);
  tr.appendChild(td2);

  counter++;
}
newField.addEventListener("click", createNewField);

function generateCode2() {
  var AccoutName = document.forms["TRF"]["accname"].value;
  var reasons = "";

  for (var a = 1; a < counter; a++) {
    reasons += "Reason " + a + ": " + document.forms["TRF"]["R" + a].value + "\n";
  }

  document.getElementById("box").value =
    "[center][img width=500 height=500]https://i.imgur.com/FuxDfcy.png[/img][/center]" +
    "[hr]" +
    "\n" +
    "[b]Dear[/b] " + AccoutName +
    "\n" +
    "After reading your Application, Imperials staffs have decided to [color=green][b]Accept[/b][/color] you. " +
    "\n" + reasons +
    "Welcome to the Family. " +
    "\n" +
    ""
}
```

```html
<form name="TRF" method="post">
  <p style="color:white">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="text-center">Accepted Format</h1>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
              <h6 class="text-uppercase"><strong><center>Accepted Format</center></strong></h6>
              <table style="width:100%" id="theTable">
                <tr>
                  <td>Applicant's Name:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="accname" size="75" placeholder="" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Reason 1:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="R1" size="75" placeholder="" required></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td id="bla">Reason 2:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="R2" size="75" placeholder="" required></td>
                </tr>

              </table>
              <h3>CODE:</h3>
              <textarea id="box" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
              <p><a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="generateCode2()" role="button">GENERATE CODE</a></p>


            </div>
            <button id="newField">
            add new field
            </button>
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, except that I want to add what the user types into the text area above the "generate code" text.
Reason Three: "User Input"

Comment: Do you have a way to do that?

Comment: When I enter the input for Reason 3, Reason 4, etc.
The input is not put in the "text area". It only displays
Reason One:
Reason Two:
While the other reasons added by the user are not displayed.

Comment: Ah I understand. Take a look at the updated generateCode2() function in my snippet above.

Comment: The script is exactly what I wanted, except that when I generate, Reason 1 looks like this: "undefinedReason 1: " I want to remove the "Undefined"

Comment: Whoops - my bad! I accidentally forgot to initialize reasons as String. Change: `var reasons;` to `var reasons = "";`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your awesome help.